# Raid 1 and raid 0 in failover?

Tags: raid

Having 10 disks, I want to use one quarter of each for a big raid 0 array and the remaining 3/4 of each for a raid 1 array having a backup of the raid 0 array. I can't do a raid 1 or both array, that would slow down the raid 0 speed.
I need 99.9% reads, mostly concurrent. Raid 1 on 2 disks doesn't seem to double the read speed to me. This is why I want a raid 0.

--

Sorry for hitting your brain. It wasn't my goal. Also sorry for my English. Point is that in raid 10 for 10 disks the read speed is 5*speed of the single drive, while in raid 0 it's 10*single drive speed. I was wondering if there was a way to combine 2 array, reading data only from the raid 0, while keeping the raid 1 for redundancy. I'm again sorry for how bad I explain myself, really. – cedivad 10 mins ago

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What is wrong with raid 10?  Given your read ratio there will be no drop in performance from raid 0

Comment: Question or no question, why are you even considering RAID 0? I'm not the first to say this and I won't be the last but RAID IS NOT BACKUP (especially if it's in the same machine).

Comment: This site is for Professional Sysadmins, and Pros never use R0 for anything they even remotely care about.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I was wondering the same. Even tried to read only every other line to see if the post had some RAID-0 joke/puzzle hidden in it. Did not. Moving along.

Comment: @Chopper3 - thinking your comment is a bit unfair - but the question is definitely back to front - choice of raid type should depend on requirements not vice versa.

Comment: Sorry for hitting your brain. It wasn't my goal. Also sorry for my English. Point is that in raid 10 for 10 disks the read speed is 5*speed of the single drive, while in raid 0 it's 10*single drive speed. I was wondering if there was a way to combine 2 array, reading data only from the raid 0, while keeping the raid 1 for redundancy. I'm again sorry for how bad I explain myself, really.

Comment: I doubt very much in the configuration you're likely to be using that you'd see any difference in performance between a R10 and R0 setup. I spend huge amounts of my time tuning storage arrays of different types and it's harder than you'd think to get the best from that number of disks. Why don't you tell us what you're trying to achieve and details of your setup (controller, buses, disk make/model, OS, FS etc.)

Answer (score 6):

This is why RAID10 was invented. Double the speed, double the redundancy.

---

Ok, after seeing your update, consider these RAID-0 figures for load time for let's say a 10Kb file (totally ficticious, but good for illustrating a point. They're totally inaccurate for real-life scenarios because they don't take into account RAID controller overheads, caches, etc):

```
1 Disk:  10.0Ms
4 Disks:  2.5Ms
8 Disks:  1.25Ms
16 Disks: 0.66Ms
```

Or for a basic RAID10:

```
1 Disk:  10.0Ms
4 Disks:  5.0Ms
8 Disks:  2.5Ms
16 Disks: 1.25Ms
```

You're losing a grand total of about 1.25Ms (in this ficticious example). In real life, these numbers are smaller and even more trivial.

The more disks you add, the lower your "return" of each additional disk will be. By the time you're up to 10 or 16 disks, each additional pair of disks only adds the tiniest amount of additional speed.

Also, as mentioned in the comments below, a decent RAID controller *will* use all the avaliable disks for reading, so over RAID-0 you lose on write speed, but not read.

Comment: Raid 10 on 10 disks moutiples by 5 the read speed, not by 10.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Cause of raid 1 doesn't double the read speed =)

Comment: This is entirely implementation-dependent.  A bad RAID1/10 driver won't load-balance the reads across all the spindles, but a good one will.  If you've bought a cheap RAID card, or are using poor software RAID, buy more discs.  If you want to get good value out of your discs, get a decent card/implementation.  Note also that read workload is important: even poor versions may well load-balance reads when the workload is multiple small random reads; balancing sequential reads is more difficult.

Comment: My workload is lots of 4kb files. I'm using a megaraid 9260, can't change it. :(

Comment: So am I right in thinking that your question is: I'm using a MegaRAID 9260 card and 10 discs, I only get half the read performance using RAID10 vs RAID0, how can I get the redundancy of RAID10 with the read performance of RAID0 without changing the card?  Because if so, the answer's simple: you can't.

Comment: If you're that bothered about read performance why aren't you looking at SSDs/FusionIO?

Comment: cause of an SSD raid for 1/2TB volume would cost me 6000€. Out of my budget. I will anyway use SSD as caching.

Comment: There are solutions that use SSDs for caching and spiny disks as a tier 2 storage; they aren't even that expensive (relatively speaking).